# iOS UITextView with attributed text not displaying from top of view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, uitextview

I have created a simple Swift app in Xcode 6.2 using storyboards and I'm using an embedded view controller to manage a UITextView that contains a few hundreds words of formatted text.

The text/view itself works perfectly and allows the user to scroll and resizes on different devices etc (using the recommend constraints) but unfortunately it always loads up the view halfway down the page and not at the top like its suppose to...

Is this a bug or something I'm doing and how do I fix it?

Cheers

Comment: I am having the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @leighton no not yet I still have no solution... I think its a bug with Xcode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having this problem as well. Create an outlet in your code to the UITextView and then add this code to viewDidLoad(),

```
myTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
```

Comment: Hi @Thomas,

I updated my code and it complied but crashed when I look at the view -

`import UIKit

class InfoViewController: UIViewController  {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextVIew: UITextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myTextVIew .scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    
    @IBAction func CloseInformation(sender:AnyObject) {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }

}`

Any thoughts why?

Comment: Did you link myTextVIew to the textView in your storyboard? If not then when `myTextVIew.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0,0))` is called it will be called on a nil optional and cause the app to crash. If that isn't the problem I'm not sure what is. @Roksalt

Comment: Thanks to @Thomas for the solution. One change though is that you need to include 'location' and 'length' in the code.

  `myTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSRange(location: 0,length: 0))`

Comment: That's `NSRange`, not `NSMakeRange` ;)

Comment: This does not seem to be working with an attributedText in the `UITextView`

Answer (score 0):

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    //sistemiamo un bug delle UITextView (se no fa vedere il testo a partire da metà e non dall'inizio)
    apDesc.hidden = false
    apDesc.scrollEnabled = false
    apDesc.text = app.summary
    apDesc.scrollEnabled = true
    apDesc.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(0, 0))

    // questo trucco va applicato per forza DOPO che la TextView è apparsa, se no non va
    // ecco perchè queste righe sono nel metodo viewDidAppear che scatta dopo che la view è comparsa

    // facciamo una piccola animazione per non far comparire di colpo il testo
    apDesc.alpha = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
        self.apDesc.alpha = 1.0
    }
}
```

**apDesc is my textView. Change with your textView name**